# Different styles in ticks on ChartJS

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Is it possible to separate styles in ticks for xAxes or draw by some other function
near.Callback - just operate with values.

For example:

[image]

Comment: Please, add some code to your question.

Comment: Please explain it properly, share code which you did.

Answer (score 4):

You can make use of the [Plugin Core API](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/plugins.html#plugin-core-api). It offers different hooks that may be used for executing custom code. In below code snippet, I use the `afterDraw` hook to [draw text](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/fillText) of different styles underneath each bars.

Note that no computation of text size is needed when composing your own labels labels. You can simply add a space to the first text section and use [`ctx.textAlign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/textAlign) 'right', then use `ctx.textAlign` 'left' for drawing the second text section.

> When drawing your own tick labels, you need to instruct Chart.js not to display the default labels. This can be done through the following definition inside the chart `options`.

```
scales: {
  xAxes: [{
    ticks: {
      display: false
    }
  }],
```

> You also need to define some padding for the bottom of the chart, otherwise you won't see your custom tick labels.

```
layout: {
  padding: {
    bottom: 20
  }
},
```

```js
new Chart(document.getElementById('myChart'), {
  type: 'bar',
  plugins: [{
    afterDraw: chart => {
      var ctx = chart.chart.ctx;
      var xAxis = chart.scales['x-axis-0'];
      var yAxis = chart.scales['y-axis-0'];
      ctx.save();
      chart.data.labels.forEach((l, i) => {
        var value = chart.data.datasets[0].data[i];
        var x = xAxis.getPixelForValue(l);
        ctx.textAlign = 'right';
        ctx.font = '12px Arial';
        ctx.fillText(l + ' ', x, yAxis.bottom + 18);
        ctx.textAlign = 'left';
        ctx.font = 'bold 14px Arial';
        ctx.fillStyle = 'blue';
        ctx.fillText(value, x, yAxis.bottom + 17);
      });
      ctx.restore();
    }
  }],
  data: {
    labels: ['Error', 'Warn', 'Info'],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'My First Dataset',
      data: [30, 59, 80],
      fill: false,
      backgroundColor: ['rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)', 'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)', 'rgba(255, 205, 86, 0.2)'],
      borderColor: ['rgb(255, 99, 132)', 'rgb(255, 159, 64)', 'rgb(255, 205, 86)', 'rgb(75, 192, 192)'],
      borderWidth: 1
    }]
  },
  options: {
    layout: {
      padding: {
        bottom: 20
      }
    },
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          display: false
        }
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

```css
canvas {
  max-width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" width="10" height="5"></canvas>
```

Comment: Where to get information of plugins?                                                         
Beacause the docs are not clear about that.