# How to style two labels in chart.js seperately

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts, chart.js, react-chartjs-2

Does anyone know how to apply different styles to the elements present inside the array which is in labels array in chart.js.See it below to take a look at what I meant.

I made chart where see the labels are shown on two lines
1.Temperature
2.Time

[image]

But I want labels to look like this:

[image]

How should I style the labels?

```
const data = {
  labels: [
    ['21°', '10am'],
    ['21°', '10am'],
    ['21°', '10am'],
    ['21°', '10am'],
    ['21°', '10am'],
    ['21°', '10am'],
  ],
  datasets: [{
    data: [21, 20, 3, 3, 3, 21],
  }, ],
};
const options = {
  xAxes: [{
    gridLines: {
      drawBorder: false,
      lineWidth: 1.8,
      zeroLineWidth: 1.8,
      zeroLineColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,.3)',
      color: 'rgba(0,0,0,.3)',
    },
    ticks: {
      fontColor: 'black',
      fontSize: 15,
      padding: 7,
    },
    scaleLabel: {
      fontColor: 'rgb(0,0,0)',
    },
  }, ],
}
```

Comment: This answer may give you a hint on how to solve your problem.: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61974056/2358409

Comment: can you tell how to use these different plugins for different cases in chart.js? where did you learn to execute these plugins.