# Chartjs xAxes gridline html (html in ticks callback)

Tags: html, chart.js

I want to use `HTML` inside `xAxes.ticks.callback`, but when I do it:

```
xAxes: [{
  ticks: {
    callback: (tickValue, index, ticks) => {
      let tickValueNew = Math.abs(tickValue) + "%";
      tickValueNew += "<br>\n" + (100 - Math.abs(tickValue));
      return tickValueNew;
    },
  },
}]
```

It doesn't work it prints `<br>` on the page, how to change this?

Comment: You cant, if you really want this you will have to adjust the code in the lib itself

Comment: When you already added <br> for a new line, what is the use \n there?

Comment: @Masood to test :) I just need new line

Answer (score 2):

You cannot define `HTML` but in order to obtain multi-line tick labels, simply let your `xAxes.ticks.callback` function return an `array`.

In your case, this could look as follows:

```
xAxes: [{
  ticks: {
    callback: v => [Math.abs(v) + '%', 100 - Math.abs(v)]
  }
}]
```

Comment: Nice, but I need to set text color too on second label

Comment: Please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/61974056/2358409. It can easily be adapted in order to obtain multi-line tick labels where each line has its own text style and color.