# Adjusting the font size and family of extra fillText labels in ChartJS

Tags: chart.js, data-visualization

I have created a pretty good ChartJS system but am having trouble with breaking the extra x-axis labels and title font details. They same to want to be the same for some reason.

First of all, the solution I got help with is here:
[SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67275805/grouping-y-axis-labels-on-multiple-lines-on-a-chartjs-with-an-extra-dimension)

The charts look okay like so:

[image]

As you can see the title and addition x-axis label are both the same font size. This occurs due to the configuration options of:

```
        // context.xAxes.font 
        context.font = this.config.get("chart.axis.font");
        context.fontSize = 100;

        context.fillStyle = this.config.get("chart.axis.font.color");
        context.textAlign = 'center';
        context.fillText(line, x, y);
```

I have the configuration options setup this way:

```
                    title: {
                        display: true,
                        fontSize: 10,                           
                        text: this.options.title,
                        padding: titlePadding,         
                    },
```

I have no idea why the fillText is working for both title and extra categories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there's no `fontSize` property on the [canvas rendering context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D). You should use its [`font`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/font) property instead to specify weight, size, and family of the font.

Please take a look at the runnable code snippet provided in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61974056/2358409).